# validate a field when a condition is true

Tags: javascript, validation

Below is my feedback page--->

```
<body class="career_bg">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="career">Career</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div id="CareerModal">

            <div class="career-logo">
                <a id="color_white" href="general_feedback"><b class="color_orange">FEEDBACK</b><b>FORM</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-body">

                                    <form id="general_feedback_form" method="post" action="general_feedback">
                                        <div class="text-danger text-center" id="leave_error"></div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <div class="text-center text-danger" id="general_feedback_error"></div>
                                                <div class="text-center text-success" id="general_feedback_success"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">                 
                                                <label>Rating :</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="stars">
                                                        <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="fed_rating" value="5"/>
                                                        <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
                                                        <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="fed_rating" value="4"/>
                                                        <label class="star star-3" for="star-2"></label>
                                                        <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="fed_rating" value="3"/>
                                                        <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
                                                        <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="fed_rating" value="2"/>
                                                        <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
                                                        <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="fed_rating" value="1"/>
                                                        <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Who You Are ?</label>
                                                <select class="form-control" name="identity" id="identity" onchange='CheckIdentity(this.value);'>
                                                <option value="">- Select -</option>
                                                <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                                                <option value="visitor">Visitor</option>
                                                <option value="student">Student</option>
                                                <option value="user">User</option>
                                                <option value="others">Others</option>

                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                            <input type="text" name="other_identity" id="other_identity"  style="display:none"
                                            class="form-first-name form-control">
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>User Name :</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Email :</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Improvement :</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="fed_improvement" id="fed_improvement"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Comments :</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="fed_comment" id="fed_comment"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message" style="display:none;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Feedback send successfully</div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error_message" style="display:none;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Feedback Not send. Try again.
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            <?php $this->load->view('Website/common/script'); ?>
            <?php $this->load->view('Website/custom'); ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want to validate the "other_identity" field only when "Others" is selected from the dropdown

Below is the script--->

div.stars {

```
            display: inline-block;
        }
        input.star { display: none; }
        label.star {
            float: right;
            padding-right: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #444;
            transition: all .2s;
        }
        input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
            content: '\f005';
            color: #FD4;
            transition: all .25s;
        }
        input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before {
            color: #FE7;
            text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
        }
        input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }
        label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }
        label.star:before {
            content: '\f006';
            font-family: FontAwesome;
        }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">


      function CheckIdentity(val)
        {
            var element=document.getElementById('other_identity');
            if(val=='others')
            {
                    element.style.display='block';
            }
            else
            {  
                    element.style.display='none';
            }
        }


            $(document).ready(function () {



                $('#general_feedback_form').bootstrapValidator({
                    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
                    feedbackIcons: {

                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },
                    excluded: ':disabled',
                    fields: {
                        user_name: {
                            validators: {
                                stringLength: {
                                    min: 2,
                                },
                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[a-z\s]+$/i,
                                    message: 'Username can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
                                },
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'User name is required'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        fed_rating: {
                            validators: {

                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Please give your rating us'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        identity: {
                            validators: {

                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Please select your identity'
                                },

                            }
                        },
                        other_identity: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Please specify your identity'
                                },

                          }
                        },
                        email: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'Your email is required'
                                },
                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i,
                                    message: 'Please enter valid email address'
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })


<!--On sucessful form validation-->
                        .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
                            //$('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                            //$('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

                            // Prevent default form submission
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var $form = $(e.target),
                                    fv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
                            $.ajax({
                                url: $form.attr('action'),
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: $form.serialize(),
                                success: function (result)
                                {
                                    if(result == '1'){
                                        $('#success_message').slideDown({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
                                        $("#general_feedback_form")[0].reset();
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            window.location = "login";
                                        }, 5000);   
                                    }else{
                                        $('#error_message').slideDown({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
                                        $('#error_message').delay(5000).fadeOut();
                                    }
                                }

                            });

                        });
            });





        </script>
```

I am using bootstrap validator to validate the fields....
Can anyone guide me how to validate the "other_identity" field only when a user selects "Others" from the dropdown

Comment: please create a jsfiddle

Comment: fiddle wont work it has other dependable links n script

Answer (score 0):

First the library you have used [bootstrapValidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator) is no longer mainteained,they suggest to move to [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/) library which has the same programming interface just replace the call with `$("your_selector).bootstrapValidator({options})` to `$("your_selector).formValidation({options})` even you don't replace the library I think the trick work on bootstrapValidator Library because they have similar api, but if not work on bootstrapValidator you can switch to formValidation library and it will work like a charm

Initially, the field validators are disabled by setting enabled: false:

```
$('#general_feedback_form').formValidation({
    fields: {
        other_identity: {
            // Disable validators
            enabled: false,
            validators: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Later, when conditions happen, these validators can be turned on by calling the enableFieldValidators() method:

```
$('#general_feedback_form').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'other_identity', true);
```

// Or the same way

```
$('#general_feedback_form').data('formValidation').enableFieldValidators('other_identity', true);
```

for further information please take a look for documentaion example
http://formvalidation.io/examples/conditional-validation/